# can I initialization int variable in unity c#?

Tags: c#

I want to try initialization int variable
and I think I can use this code.

```
result = int.Parse("");
```

Is it work or error?

Comment: You've tagged two distinct programming languages. Which one are you using? The code looks like C#.

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you want to initialize an integer variable by parsing a string containing that integer?

Comment: And why not `result = 1;` or something?

Comment: If you want to know whether something will work, why not **try it**?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is `c#`. You probably rather ment `unity3d` though this question seems not specific to Unity but about `c#` in general

Answer (score 1):

First of all int.Parse(someString) could produce an exception if the string couldn't be parsed so if you really need to initialize with the value inside a string the better aproach is:

```
int result = -1; //or any other value that points to an inizialization error
int.TryParse(someString, out result);
```

or in one line as @Uwe Keim points:

```
int result;
if (!int.TryParse(someString, out result)) result = -1;
```

also you can use the *horrible* try/catch aproach (if for some weird reason you're binded to Parse instead TryParse):

```
int result;
try
{
    result = int.Parse(someString);
}
catch
{
   result = -1; //or any other value that points to an inizialization error
}
```

Or, of course if someString is a constant value you didn't need all the parse problem:

```
result = 0;
```

Comment: Try catch is a _horrible_ approach.

Comment: Better use `if (!int.TryParse(someString, out result)) result = -1;` or something like that.

Comment: Edited to include the one line with if and some explanation of why the try/catc aproach (I included only to emphasize that Parse MUST be controlled